# Why is there not enough space for the words to fit in, in this animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, css-animations

I am trying to display a passing text animation in the homepage of my website.

There are two texts that needs to show up. "you've come to the right place" and " we care about you", next to the welcome text.

For some reason, this is how it looks like:
[image]

I want the welcome! text to appear followed quickly by the first quote, after a few seconds, the welcome and the first quote should dissapear and the second quote should appear.

CSS

```
/* animation  welcome text styling  */

.intro{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.intro1 {  
  animation: showup 7s infinite;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:35px;
  color: purple;

}

.intro2 {

 font-size:30px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
  width:400px;


}

.sub-head {
  margin-left:-355px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

@keyframes showup {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    20% {opacity:1;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% { margin-left:-800px; }
    20% { margin-left:-600px; }
    35% { margin-left:0px; }
    100% { margin-left:0px; }
}

@keyframes reveal {
    0% {opacity:0;width:0px;}
    20% {opacity:1;width:0px;}
    30% {width:355px;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;width:355px;}
}


/* end of text animation */
```

HTML:

```
<div class= "first-box"> 


<!-- a welcome text is placed here to grasp the users' attention to the website. -->

 <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
  <div class="intro intro2">
    <span class="sub-head "> You've come to the right place</span>
    <span class="sub-head inactive">We care about you </span>
  
  </div>



 

  </div>
```

JS:

```
// sets the interval for which the function will run, in this case 8 seconds, (8000)
setInterval(function() {
  // grab all elements with class 'sub-head' and stores it in the elems const. 
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-head')


  elems.forEach(e => {
     // check if the element has a class 'inactive', if there is one, remove it
    if (e.classList.contains('inactive')) e.classList.remove('inactive')
    // if not, add it. This is how it creates a loop. 
    else e.classList.add('inactive');
  });
}, 8000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make some changes

```js
const timeout = 15000
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-head')
//for each slide make equal times
const forEachSlide = timeout / elems.length
const intro1 = document.querySelector('.intro1')
const intro2 = document.querySelector('.intro2')

//change timeouts of intros (also can set in the css file)
intro1.style.animationDuration = `${timeout}ms`
intro1.style.animationIterationCount = 'infinite'
intro2.style.animationDuration = `${timeout/2}ms`
intro2.style.animationIterationCount = 'infinite'

//timeout of each '.inactive'changes
  let showId = setTimeout(function blockShow(){
    elems.forEach(e => {
      if (e.classList.contains('inactive')) {
        e.classList.remove('inactive')  
      } else e.classList.add('inactive');
  });
    showId = setTimeout(blockShow, forEachSlide)
  }, forEachSlide)
```

```css
.intro{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro1 {  
  animation-name: showup;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:35px;
  color: purple;
}

.intro2 {
 font-size:30px;
 animation-name: reveal;
 /*width auto makes the block size of this content so all words fit in it*/
  width:auto;
  /*max-width makes maximum width of block where words can be placed*/
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.sub-head{
  display: none;
}

.sub-head.inactive {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:-355px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes showup {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    20% {opacity:1;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes slidein {
    0% { margin-left:-800px; }
    20% { margin-left:-600px; }
    35% { margin-left:0px; }
    100% { margin-left:0px; }
}

@keyframes reveal {
    0% {opacity:0;width:0px;}
    20% {opacity:1;width:0px;}
    30% {width:auto;}
    80% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;width:auto;}
}
```

```html
<div class= "first-box"> 

 <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
  <div class="intro intro2">
    <span class="sub-head "> You've come to the right place</span>
    <span class="sub-head inactive">We care about you </span>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `inactive` class and set width to 455 (at `@keyframes reveal`):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-head')
  elems.forEach(e => {
    if (e.classList.contains('inactive')) e.classList.remove('inactive')
    else e.classList.add('inactive');
  });
}, 8000)
```

```css
.intro{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro1 {  
  animation: showup 7s infinite;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:35px;
  color: purple;
}

.intro2 {
  font-size:30px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
  width:400px;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}
.sub-head {
  margin-left:-5px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  20% {opacity:1;}
  80% {opacity:1;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% { margin-left:-800px; }
  20% { margin-left:-600px; }
  35% { margin-left:0px; }
  100% { margin-left:0px; }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {opacity:0;width:0px;}
  20% {opacity:1;width:0px;}
  30% {width:455px;}
  80% {opacity:1;}
  100% {opacity:0;width:455px;}
}
```

```html
<div class= "first-box"> 
  <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
  <div class="intro intro2">
    <span class="sub-head "> You've come to the right place</span>
    <span class="sub-head inactive">We care about you </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou so much for this. The only problem that remains is that the words don't fit in the box. as you can see, the last word in the animation is cut off. how can I fix this. thanks again

Comment: You are welcome :) check updated answer pls

Comment: you have saved me weeks of hustle

Comment: I need this for an assignment, can you please tell me what was wrong and how you fixed it?

Comment: You did well JS part, You just forgot to make css class for hiding elements, and for width, you set fixed width in animation, so it was too small for content